# Asp.Net dropdown list and label not displaying inline

Tags: css, asp.net

I have an asp.net dropdown list with a css class who's markup is

```
  .form-control {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 34px;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.42857143;
      color: #555;
      background-color: #fff;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
      -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
              transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }
```

I have a label which is supposed to be on the same line as the dropdown so to achieve this I added another css class:

```
.inlineControl {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

the dropdown control has both classes in it's cssClass property and the inlineControl is last so it should over ride the display: block of the form-control class. However in the browser the label is above the dropdown not beside it. I checked the developer tools f12 and the styles window shows that the inlineControl class is overriding the form-control class and the display should be inline-block, and so also in the computed window it shows that the display is supposed to be inline-block.
The markup of the controls is:

```
<div>
   <label>לקוח</label>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="comboClients" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inlineControl" DataTextField="ClientName" DataValueField="ClientId">
```

What's causing the controls to display as block and how can I get them to display inline?

Answer (score 1):

The problem apparently is the width: 100%. I changed it to 90% and it's displaying properly.